# Remove blank spaces caused by justified alignment in paragraphs coming from tinymce editor

Tags: css, text, responsive-design, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE as a text editor plugin to insert news on the website.

I'm trying to get my paragraphs have a justified alignment, but I'm having some problems, white space between words.

Im trying to solve this using word-spacing but it only works sometimes.

The code Im using to my paragraph is only this:

```
.news p{
    font-size: 14px;  
    text-align:justify;
    line-height:25px;
    margin:5px auto;
}
```

Do you know some method to solve this white spaces?

Comment: may be this will help http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-wrap.asp

Comment: check this one too http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp